# Correspondence: Derivations and vector fields

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, vector-fields, smooth-functions, derivations

Let $D$ be a derivation on the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. By the Hadamard lemma we find a smooth function $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x)=f(0)+x\cdot g(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I was able to show that then the following identity holds:  $$D(f)=D(\operatorname{id}_\mathbb{R})\cdot g + \operatorname{id}_\mathbb{R} \cdot D(g).$$ In particular, we have $$D(f)(0)=D(\operatorname{id}_\mathbb{R})(0)\cdot g(0).$$ I am struggling to show that, more generally, we have $$D(f)(x)=D(\operatorname{id}_\mathbb{R})(x)\cdot g(x)$$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Any hints?

Comment: That’s false even for the usual derivative.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: I see. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411485/show-there-is-an-isomorphism-between-the-vector-fields-and-the-derivations/3411699#comment10020827_3411699) in step three the above identity is claimed, however, I think. Is this claim false or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What is written there is different from your incorrect conclusion. The function $g$ there depends on the point $z$. So, the logic goes: pick $z$, then there are corresponding $g_i$ such that $f(x)=f(z)+\sum(x^i-z^i)g_{z,i}(x)$ and $g_{z,i}(z)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(z)$. Taking $D$ gives $Df=\sum(x^i-z^i)Dg_{z,i}+\sum D(x^i)g_{z,i}$. If you now evaluate at the point $z$, the first term vanishes so you get $D(f)(z)=\sum D(x^i)(z)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(z)$. Notice how there are no more $g$’s anymore. This is the formula which holds for all $z$.

Comment: So, if you want, you can write this as $Df=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\,D(x^i)$. Throughout, $x^i$ is interpreted as the function $(p^1,\dots, p^n)\mapsto p^i$ (along with a suitable bump function, if you haven’t already proved the necessary localization lemmas).